# Set the number of Lines in a Multi-Line Textbox in WPF/UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Is there some way of binding to height property of a TextBox such that I can specify the number of lines of height from Xaml for a Multi-Line Textbox?

```
<!-- Multi-Line TextBox -->
<TextBox Name="A1Notes" Header="Notes" 
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             Height="{Binding ???? 10 Lines ????}"/>
```

Comment: I don't know WPF but doesn't it related with font family/size you use?

Comment: Probably need to measure size of font height and multiply by number of lines.  What I want is really an attached property that can do this work for me for TextBox in Xaml.  (not sure binding is correct solution because it can't evaluate an expression to calculate a height)

Comment: http://www.codemag.com/article/1405061/XAML-Magic--Attached-Properties

Comment: Bill Moore, Instead of replying my comment, improve your question with necessary information

Comment: Firstly please tell what's application you are developing, WPF or UWP. They're different although both of them using  XAML. Did you need solution for one of them or both? Secondly, could you please detail what's  "the number of lines of height" mean, since I'm confused about your issue. You could also provide information about why you need this feature.

Comment: @BillMoore, did you finy any solution for `UWP` ?